# convergence to zero from a differential inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a non-negative function $y(t)$ such that $$y'\leq \frac{1}{N} + y + \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} +y}$$ for all $t\geq 0$, with $y(0) = 0$ and $N >>1$. Is it possible to prove that $$\lim_{N\to \infty} y(t) = 0$$ for any finite $t$ (say $t\in [0,T]$)? If not, will there be a counter-example? I am really stuck at these as classical Gronwall lemma cannot be applied (at least trivially). Thanks for any relevant help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement does not hold. Consider the case when your condition holds with equality. Then you can explicitly integrate the ODE (I will call $1/N=a$)
$$
y'=a+y+\sqrt{a+y}.
$$
You can separate the variables to get
$$
\frac{dy}{a+y+\sqrt{a+y}}=dx
$$
Integration gives
$$
2\ln(\sqrt{a+y}+1)=C+x
$$
Since you need $y(0)=0$ you have $C=2\ln(1+\sqrt{a})$. Your solution (unique) is
$$
y_a(x)=[(1+\sqrt{a})e^{x/2}-1]^2-a.
$$
Given any $x>0$, the limit as $a\to 0$ is then
$$
y_0(x)=[e^{x/2}-1]^2
$$
which is positive. BTW this last function is the non-trivial solution corresponding to $a=0$ (for $a=0$ uniqueness is lost).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I think there is a mistake, why $y(0) =0$ implies $C = 1+\sqrt{1+a}$?

Comment: You are right. I fixed it. Just a typo

Comment: shouldn't be $C = 2\log(1+\sqrt{a})$?

Comment: You are right again! Let me edit

Comment: The rest seems correct. I had copied the constant from the wrong place on my paper.